# React / NextJS - onClick targets all mapped items - how do i target just one?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Couldn't figure out a better way to word the problem i have, sorry if this gets asked often.

Code is like this:

```
  const [isFlipped, setFlipped] = useState(false);

  const flip = () => {
    if (!isFlipped) {
      setFlipped(true);
    } else {
      setFlipped(false);
    }
  };
return(
data.map((product) => (
  <div 
    onClick={()=> flip()}
    animate={isFlipped && { rotateY: 180 }}
>
    <p>{product.name}</p>
    <p>{product.info}</p>
  </div>
 ));
)
```

i want the `flip()` function to work only on the div that gets clicked, however currently it affects every mapped div.

Comment: Do you mean you want the action to be called only on the click of `p` (Paragraph element)?

Comment: The flip() function is supposed to flip the div 180deg when clicked - however it flips ALL divs.

Comment: I updated my answer since you showed the flip() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit (After seeing the flip function): You should make this a seperate component so each child has it's own isFlipped State. And then map and create the components with the product as a prop.

Add a key to the div in the map to add uniqueness.

```js
data.map((product, key) => (
  <div key={key} onClick={()=> flip()}>
    <p>{product.name}</p>
    <p>{product.info}</p>
  </div>
 ));
```

Comment: Thanks, i changed it, however still not quite sure how to target a 'key' when it's clicked.

Comment: Thanks again! I got it working today, by doing what you said. Though for some reason the animation now happens endlessly. While `isFlipped = true`, the animation just repeats.